# Non orientable surface of genus $g$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Assume we have $g\ge 2$ and a regular $2g$-gon with vertices $z_1,...,z_{2g}$. Let $N_g$ be the quotient space of $E_{2g}$ by the relation $$(1-t)z_{2j-1}+tz_{2j}\sim(1-t)z_{2j}+tz_{2j+1},$$ where the indices are $\mod 2g$.

$N_g$ is called the non orientable surface of genus $g$. Can someone justify that name? Why is $N_g$ non orientable?

Comment: If you cut the polygon into $g$ wedge-shaped pieces by joining every other vertex to the center, each wedge glues to a Moebius strip, i.e., a real projective plane with a disk removed. The entire surface is consequently the $g$-fold connected sum of $g$ projective planes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take j=1, just for clearness.
Consider that the segments $(1−t)z_1+tz_2$ and $(1−t)z_2+tz_3$, where $1/3 \leq t \leq 2/3$, are identified point-to-point by the equivalence relation.
Draw a neighbourhood of the two segments in the polygon, and join the starting point of the first segment to the correspondinfg point of the second segment remaining in the neighbourhood you have drawn, and do the same for the end points.
You should have got a Moebius strip: by definition, a surface that "contains" a Moebius strip is non-orientable (a motivation may be the following: if a surface contains a Moebius strip and is assumed to be smooth, then you can not define a normal smooth vector field on the whole surface).

The fact that this surface has a property named "genus" that is equal to $g$ requires, to be justified, to talk about the fundamental group of a surface, and is a little more complicated...