# Homotopy equivalent surfaces after removal of a point

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to figure whether a surface $\Sigma_g/N_{g'}$ orientable/non-orientable is homotopy equivalent after removing a point.

For the orientable case I know the fundamental group is:

$\pi_1(\Sigma_g)=<a_1,b_1,...,a_g,b_g|[a_1,b_1],...,[a_g,b_g]>$

With a point removed the fundamental group becomes: $\pi_1(\vee_{2g} S_1)==*_{2g}\mathbb{Z}$.

I know that one should check if the two groups are isomorphic or not but I'm not sure how to do this since I'm quite new to topology.

Comment: Try doing the deformation retract in the (unquotiented) polygons. You should be able to show a torus and s Klein bottle -- both missing a point -- are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: @SteveD I don't see how this is related to my problem.

Comment: @Linus isn't this the $g=1$ case for your question? If not, then your question might be unclear. It would be helpful to maybe rewrite it.

Comment: The point is in either case (orientable or unorientable) the surface can be realized as the quotient of  a $4n$-gon see [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Teo.pdf) for example. The trick then, is to remove a point from the interior of the polygon, and do a deformation retract to the boundary. You can then show, that in the (orientable or unorientable) case you have that both resulting spaces are homeomorphic after retracting to the boundary. This shows (with some work) that both spaces are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: The non-orientable case was asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586658/does-the-punctured-non-orientable-surface-of-genus-g-deformation-retract-to-a/3586804#3586804). The construction is almost exactly the same in the orientable case, except for using a different polygon gluing pattern.